# add new index using array map function in php without using looping function

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

this is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 277558
            [text_value] => Jif
            [response_count] => 13
            [response_percentage] => 92
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 277559
            [text_value] => Peter Pan
            [response_count] => 20
            [response_percentage] => 6
        )
)
```

after completing the operation the out put should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 277558
            [text_value] => Jif
            [response_count] => 13
            [response_percentage] => 92
            [encode_param]=>ds!@@^(*!ggsfh8236542jsdgf82*&61327
        )
    [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 277559
                [text_value] => Peter Pan
                [response_count] => 20
                [response_percentage] => 6
                [encode_param]=>ds!@@^(*!ggsfh8236542jsdgf82*&61327
            )
)
```

you can see a new array value encode_paramis added

in that function do some encode algorithms

i have achieve this in the foreach looping statement 
but i need to do it in array maping

Can anybody help thank u in advance

Comment: Have you actually looked at [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) at all?

Comment: ya i have done some search on it but i could not fine the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$encode_func = function($elem) {   // declare function to encode
  return $elem['text_value']; 
}

$result = array_map(function($elem) use($encode_func) { 
  $elem['encode_param'] = $encode_func($elem);
  return $elem;
}, $array);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it doesn't provide me the desire array the out put is like thisArray
(
    [text_value] => Array
        (
            [encode_param] => c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d
        )

    [text_value1] => Array
        (
            [encode_param] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
        )

)

Comment: @DeepakKumar Are you sure you pass **your** array as last param in call to `array_map()`?